# Persistent mesh ID for the same three.js object?

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber

If I load the **same model twice** in three.js, their meshes have dynamically generated IDs e.g.

```
{
    "uuid": "33FA38D9-0AAC-4657-9BBE-5E5780DDFB2F",
    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
},
{
    "uuid": "16F2E381-2B73-44C4-A7BB-38D7E1CD2381",
    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
}
```

These 2 ids are essentially corresponsing to the same mesh.

Is there a way / best practice way to create an identifier for this mesh, such that on every load, there is a "persistent" ID for the mesh for a given object?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a consistent way to identify an object, I recommend you use [`Object.name`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.name). This way you could search for it later with [`Object.getObjectByName()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.getObjectByName)

```js
object.name = "MyUsefulThing"
scene.add(object);

// ...

let search = scene.getObjectByName("MyUsefulThing");
```

The `Object.id` property is labelled `readonly` in the docs, so it might be used internally by the renderer, and modifying it is not recommended.

Comment: I am familiar with this approach, but it's non-unique. I can technically traverse the whole object and assign my own, custom uuids and store them as `name`. 

Is that the best approach?

Comment: @GRS Yes, you could create your own UUID and assign it to `.name`. Out of curiosity, why do you need the UUIDs to be persistent?

Comment: for modification purposes. E.g. I have an original model, which is further customized. I do not want to re-save the customized version (since there could be N of them created), but rather, apply the delta from the original on load. This way I only store 1 model and N small deltas, rather than N big objects.